# How to get the name of clicked image and compare it with a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript

Two images, placed by php:

```
echo "<img onclick='test()' src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";
echo "<img onclick='test()' src=\"/img/Moon.png."\">";
$x = "Sun.png";
```

js:

```
function test(){
if (clicked_image_name == $x) ...do something
```

So, how to get the name of clicked image, and how to compare it with a php variable ?

Comment: Is your Javascript inline or in a separate file? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065712/export-javascript-when-the-script-is-using-php-variables

Comment: try this one, function test(){ if (clicked_image_name == '<?php echo $x?>') ...do something

Comment: to get image name you can try this one,echo "<img onclick='test(this.src)' src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value of $x in a hidden field. You'd be able to take the value then from javascript

Comment: @ Rafael, is the hidden field secure enough ragarding spamboot. And, any idea about getting clicked_image_name ?

Comment: Ok, I will try this idea and somehow get the image name. Thanks a lot to EveryOne.

Comment: How @fluty indicates you in his answer, add the image's name as an argument to test() function. In this way you'd have the image's name and only rest to you get the X value using document.getElementById(Id_hidden_field)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<img onclick='test(this.src)' src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";
echo "<img onclick='test(this.src)' src=\"/img/Moon.png."\">";
```

js:

```
function test(img_src){
var clicked_image_name = img_src.substring(5);
if (clicked_image_name == '<?php echo $x;?>') ...do something
```

above code snippets will do your job.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing,

You can declare one javascript variable and its value by php code :-

```
var imageName = "<?php echo "Sun.png"?>";
```

and you can modify the php code to pass image src name as variable:

```
echo "<img onclick='test("Sun.png")' src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";
```

And then in javscription test() function, you can check its value

```
function test(imageSrcName)
{
   if(imageSrcName == imageName)
   {
       alert("both image name are same");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("both image name are different");
   }
}
```

Comment: @ Pushkar, $x is a changeable variable, after reload the page it may have another value, i.e. `$x = "Moon";`

Comment: yes.. then your imageName variable value will get change and same image source name.
Please let me know the issue which you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add an argument to the test() call to your php page like the following:

```
echo "<img onclick='test(\"$mysunvariable\")'  src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";
echo "<img onclick='test(\"$mymoonvariable\")' src=\"/img/Moon.png."\">";
```

And in your JS:

```
function test(name){
   if(name == 'Sun.jpg'){
      do something
   }
   other cases..
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need to compare with PHP dynamic variables, you should write a PHP service and call it by an async GET or POST (for example using AJAX).

In that case to get the image name you can add the name parameter to each of your images in your PHP page like this:

```
echo "<img onclick='test(this)' name=\"sun\"  src=\"/img/Sun.png."\">";
echo "<img onclick='test(this)' name=\"moon\" src=\"/img/Moon.png."\">";
```

And then modify your JS function as below:

```
function test(img){
   var myname = img.name;
   here you do your async stuff
...
}
```

Comment: @ Gio, yes, $x is a dynamic variable, changed after each page reloading. AnyWay, Thanks a lot

Comment: @Alegro: consider the second part of my anser and rate it please.

Comment: If i must write ajax procedure for comparing - ok, but I must before get the clicked_image_name.

Comment: @Alegro I just edited my previous answer to give you an idea of that!

Comment: Thanks, Gio, I see. Very near the solution.